# Two continuous functions such that $f(z)^2=g(z)^2=1-z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find a domain $D$ and two continuous functions $f$ and $g$ such that $$f(z)^2=g(z)^2=1-z^2$$ for all $z\in D$. 
This is what I tried.  Consider $$h(z)=e^{{1/2}L(z)}$$ where $L$ is a branch of logarithm such that $$L(z)=\log|z|+iArg(z)$$. And $D$=$\mathbb{C}$\ {$z|1-z^2 \in(-\infty,0]$}. This is all I could think of. Am I on the right track? Thanks

Comment: You probably meant $h(z) = e^{1/2 L(1-z^2)}$? The right track, but not the only possibility. Generally, what are the problems when you try to define $\sqrt{\varphi(z)}$ for a holomorphic/continuous $\varphi$?

Comment: Yep sorry about that mistake. Well finding the proper domain to define the branch right?

Comment: Well, yes, finding a suitable domain is a problem. I meant something before that, though: when you try to do it locally, pick a point and try to define a square root of $\varphi$ on some small neighbourhood of the point, where does that work nicely, and where do you have problems?

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not really sure but I guess points that maps onto only another point or one to one points will work nicely. I am sorry for any wrong use of mathematical terms

Comment: When you try to define $\sqrt{z}$, at which point do you have a _local_ obstruction?

Comment: @DanielFischer I am sorry I am not familiar with the term local obstruction.

Comment: It's not a technical term. I meant, at which point $p$ can you not even define a continuous branch of $\sqrt{z}$ in any small neighbourhood of $p$?

Comment: zero right?....

Comment: Right. Everywhere else, you can locally define a branch of the square root (and have a second by multiplying with $-1$). So if you look at $\sqrt{\varphi(z)}$, where does it locally work without problems, and where do you have a problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to find *some* domain $D$ in which $f$ and $g$ are to live, the unit disk will do nicely. When $|z|<1$, the real part of $1-z^2$ is positive. In the right half plane  the principal branch of square root is holomorphic (it is defined there as $re^{i\theta}\mapsto \sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$ for $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$), allowing for a direct definition of $f(z)=\sqrt{1-z^2}$ and $g(z)=-\sqrt{1-z^2}$.  (I assume that taking $f\equiv g$ would be somehow cheating.)

There are some larger domains too. Any simply connected domain not containing $\pm 1$ would do, but perhaps with a less direct argument.